# Look for ocurrences of items in files in bash

Tags: bash, shell

I have a bash script as follows. It basically loads the contents from a text file into a variable, then reads each line from that variable and tries to find matches of a pattern containing that item in the files under a certain folder, and finally generates a list with the items with matches.

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

set -e

var_with_items=$(<"/path/to/file")
matches=""
while IFS= read -r item; do
  echo "- ${item}"
  pattern="foo/bar/${item}/"
  uses=$(grep -r "/some/path" -e "${pattern}" | wc -l)
  if [[ "${uses}" != "0" ]]; then
    matches+="${item}\n";
  fi
done < <(printf "%s\n" "$var_with_items")
```

The problem I'm facing is that it only checks the first line from the variable (the first item) and I don't know what the problem is because it doesn't throw any error. However, if I comment the line `uses=$(grep -r "/some/path" -e "${pattern}" | wc -l)`, it correctly prints every line from `$var_with_items`, so I guess the problem is in that line, but if I execute it manually (with proper item substitution) it works.

UPDATE:
In my original question I didn't add `set -e` at the top of the script, which makes it exit as soon as a command exits with non-zero status. That being said, as `grep` exits with `0` when matches are detected, and `1` otherwise, it was making the script to exit as soon as it process the first item without matches.

Comment: Depending on the version of `grep` you have, it might not allow specifying options (like `-e`) after the first positional argument (and the first positional argument is supposed to be the pattern to search for). Try `grep -r "${pattern}" "/some/path"` and see if that solves it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @GordonDavisson, but I'm afraid that's not the problem because I've tried to execute `grep -r "/some/path" -e "${pattern}"` and it works.

Comment: The next thing I'd try is putting `set -x` before the relevant section, and see if that shows anything unexpected (e.g. unexpected/nonprinting characters in the variables, etc).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my original question I didn't add `set -e` at the top of the script, which makes it exit as soon as a command exits with non-zero status. That being said, as `grep` exits with `0` when matches are detected, and `1` otherwise, it was making the script to exit as soon as it process the first item without matches.

Answer (score 0):

`grep` command with option `-o` returns every matched pattern in a line.

Therefore suggesting:

```
  grep -r -o "/some/path" -e "${pattern}" | wc -l
```

Or:

```
  uses=$(grep -r -o "/some/path" -e "${pattern}" | wc -l)
```